# Можно ли подключать файл дважды в PHP

Tags: php, переменные, include, require

Делаю небольшой проект на PHP.
Все переменные с текстами у меня находятся в отдельном файле.
Этот файл подключён через include в самом начале главного скрипта.
У меня в текстах есть переменная среди текстов `$txt = "бла бла бла $njpx['$nsx'] бла";`, которая по ключу обращается к переменной, которая объявляется ПОСЛЕ подключения файла с текстами.
Из-за этого переменная не отображается в тексте.
Чтобы решить это, я ЕЩЁ РАЗ подключил тот же файл только после объявления нужных мне переменных, и оно заработало, без ошибок.
Суть вопроса: так вообще можно делать, подключать один и тот же файл дважды в одном скрипте? Или есть какой-то способ сделать это изящнее? Спасибо!

Comment: Мало что понятно, добавьте, пожалуйста, конкретные куски кода с местами подключения файла, объявления переменными и вывода.

Comment: Жуть какая. `include` потому и отличается от `include_once`, что можно подключать один и тот же файл несколько раз. Но суть не в этом. Переменные должны быть объявлены до того, как будут использованы. И никак по другому. _"оно заработало, без ошибок"_ - нет, оно отработало с ошибками, просто у вас не настроен вывод ошибок должным образом.

Answer (score 0):

> так вообще можно делать, подключать один и тот же файл дважды в одном скрипте?

Можно. Зависит от задачи. Часто применяется такой подход в шаблонизации. Как минимум `include` и `require` включают и выполняет указанный файл.

А вот подключать файл **до** переменной, от которой требуется какое-то значение - не имеет никакого смысла, т.к. код выполняется последовательно и построчно и логично, что если в файле нужно оперировать переменной, то подключать его надо **после**

Comment: Просто есть код, который использует данные из подключаемого файла раньше. И подключить его позже нельзя.

Comment: Сочувствую. Придётся решать эту дилемму ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯